# SSRS 2008, Report table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

In a report table how do i assign a variable as a link to a value which is a URL           eg. [link] has to change to "click here to view the URL" when clicking it should the display the value which is a url or take you directly to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click the text box, select properties and configure like this:

[image]

and on the expression, do:

```
="http://your_url/"+Fields!Your_field.Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Onother Question, When i restated my Machine on my ssrs project, the grouping pane(where is says 'row Group' and 'Column Group') is graded out how do i resolve this?

Comment: Hi guru. Usually by clicking on your data table on the report it should make it available. About the voting, there is an up arrow above the number zero on the beginning of the question. Please vote to indicate the answer was useful. thanks